# How does setReceiveTimeout work in pooled actor context?

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-actor

I am working on some logic which involves shutting down idle actors. However these actors are pooled actors, which means the `ReceiveTimeout` message is sent to all the actors in the pool.

The problem I'm running into is that if I have 5 actors in the pool, when the pool receives a message, only one of them has their timeout reset. The rest 4, since they did not receive a message are still on the original `TimeOut` clock, which makes sense as per the framework. But for my usecase I want it such that if one of the actors in the pool receives a message, the timeout is reset for all. How can I accomplish this? One crude way I have thought of is that as soon as one actor in the pool receives a message, it sends a heartbeat to the rest of the actors in the pool. But not sure how to achieve this in Akka.

My actor is started in this manner -

```
Props.create(ActorA.class, () -> new ActorA()).withRouter(new SmallestMailboxPool(poolSize));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By pooled actors I am assuming you mean a router with pool characteristics? Presuming that, look at broadcast messages under the [specially handled messages](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/routing.html#specially-handled-messages) handling section of the docs.

Set the receiveTimeout on the router and then send a broadcast message to the workers in the handler for that timeout in the router.